# Handling itemClick of listview windows

Tags: c#, json, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am populating listview as follows in windows 8.1 app using c#

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);

        List<Notice> items = new List<Notice>();

        foreach (var o in obj)
        {
            Notice notice = new Notice();
            items.Add(new Notice() { title = o["title"], from = o["from"] });
        }
        NoticeBinding.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    public class Notice
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string from { get; set; }
        public string sendername { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
    }
```

This gives me a proper listView. I want to handle the itemClick event. For corresponding "id" in the JSON response there is a "title" , "content" and "sender" of the notice. So once I click on any listview item corresponding notice should be shown. The following is a part of my JSON response

```
{
"id":20,
"title":"Testing after phase 2 is shifted to server",
"from":"Administrator",
"sendername":"ABX",
"day":"Tuesday",
"dateofMonth":"20th",
"month":"May",
"year":2014,
"date":"Tuesday, 20th May, 2014",
"content":"Ready. Set. Go"
}
```

In the list View only "title" and "from" is shown. But after clicking it should display title, content, sender. Any help?

Comment: So why are you only populating `Notice` with with `title` and `from`? Have you tried populating it with all the properties you need?

Comment: That's the list which shows only title name and sender. Just like email app. So after clicking on notice it will show the content of the notice, the sender , the title etc

Answer (score 1):

Set `IsItemClickEnabled` property to true and use `ItemClick` click event in `ListView`. You can access clicked item by accessing its argument object `ItemClickEventArgs` , i.e. `e.ClickedItem` where `e` is `ItemClickEventArgs`